# Неполная загрузка Jquery

Tags: html, jquery

Создаю сайт. Демо-версия [тут](http://alim-ne-vinovat.myjino.ru/portfolio.html).

Если зайти по прямой ссылке — все открывается хорошо, а если с сайта, то в какие-то моменты создается ощущение, что он не видит *JS*.

В чем может быть проблема и как её исправить?

Comment: Сайт вообще не открывается

Comment: [ссылка](http://alim-ne-vinovat.myjino.ru/portfolio.html)

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У тебя файл

http://alim-ne-vinovat.myjino.ru/js/jquery-1.11.2.js

кончается вызовом

```
jQuery.noConflict();
```

Убери эту строчку и есть вероятность, что всё заработает.

Comment: Я убрал, но все равно при переходе с главной или контакта в портфолио - изображения выстраиваются строго по левой стороне в столбик. Я не уверен, но мне кажется я что-то упускаю в файле http://alim-ne-vinovat.myjino.ru/js/main.js

Comment: @AlimKhasanov, не убрал.

Comment: а сейчас в чем ошибка?

Comment: @AlimKhasanov, а может сам подебажишь?

Comment: @Qwetriy так я и дебажу